# Is there any way to order the results of a Cancan accessible_by call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I am using the Cancan `accessible_by` to retrieve a ActiveRecord::Relation result (example code below). Is there any way to order the results during the `accessible_by` call?

UPDATE: Srdjan's was correct. `@attributes` was already being set using `accessible_by`. I have updated the example to show the sort by User's login. `Attribute` has a `belongs_to` relationship with `User`.

```
class AttributesController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def index
    @attributes = @attributes.includes(:user).order("#{User.table_name}.login")
  end

  # GET /attribute/1
  # GET /attribute/1.xml
  def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @attribute }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the horse's mouth, as it were.

> `@articles = Article.accessible_by(current_ability, :update)`
>   This is an Active Record scope so other scopes and pagination can be chained onto it.

Source: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Fetching-Records

Also, on the top of that page, you'll note that as of CanCan 1.4, this is done automatically when you call `load_resource`. Are you on that version?